# AWS CDK: retrieve a list of provisioned Hosted Zones in AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cdk

Although the AWS CLI provides a straightforward way to retrieve a list of all provisioned Route 53 Hosted Zones in the AWS account, there seems to be no way to do this via the AWS CDK.

In the documentation of the [`HostedZone`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_route53/HostedZone.html) class in the Python AWS CDK, there exist only a [`from_lookup()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_route53/HostedZone.html#aws_cdk.aws_route53.HostedZone.from_lookup) method to lookup a Hosted Zone if you have the Id and Domain Name available using the

On the other hand the AWS CLI has the [`list-hosted-zones`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-hosted-zones.html) command to get a list of Hosted Zones without providing any parameter.

I want to get a list of the Hosted Zones Ids in the end, but I can't seem to find any way to do with the CDK. Any help would be appreciated!

Tried asking ChatGPT and it misled me to believing that there exists a `list()` method in the `aws_cdk.aws_route53.HostedZone` class to do this. There exists no such method.

Comment: You'd typically use boto3, the AWS SDK for Python for this.  See the Route 53 client's [list_hosted_zones](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53/client/list_hosted_zones.html) method.  What's the CDK use case?

Comment: The CDK exists specifically for creating a CloudFormation template that is then used to provision resources in AWS. Why would you want to use that just to query for existing resources? The SDK is what you need to be using for your task, not the CDK.